# Add GeoServer WMS layer on web page using OpenLayers

Tags: wms, asp.net, openlayers

I am trying to add GeoServer WMS Layer using OpenLayers on the web page.

And here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WMSLayer.aspx.cs" Inherits="OpenLayerMap.WebPages.WMSLayer" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers WMS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>WMS Layer</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG: 4326',
            extent: [90, -180, -90, 180]
        });

        // source
        var layerSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ShapeFile/wms?',
            params: {
                'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                'LAYERS': 'afg_adm2',
                'TILED': true,
                'bbox': [60.5048675537109, 29.361572265625, 74.8941345214844, 38.4909286499023], 
                'CRS': 'EPSG:404000',
                'height': 487,
                'width': 768,
                'FORMAT': 'image/png'
            },
            serverType: 'geoserver',
        });

        // layer
        var layerLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            layer: 'afg_adm2',
            visible: true,
            preload: Infinity,
            source: layerSource
        });

        // view
        var olview = new ol.View({
            //projection: 'ESPG:4326',
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
            //extent: projection.getExtent(),
            zoom: 1.2
        })

        // map
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
                doubleClickZoom: false,
                dragAndDrop: false,
                dragPan: true,
                keyboardPan: false,
                keyboardZoom: false,
                mouseWheelZoom: false,
                pointer: false,
                select: false
            }),
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attribution: true,
                zoom: true,
            }),
            renderer: 'canvas', 
            view: olview,
            layers: [
              new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.OSM()
              }),
              layerLayer
            ],
            controls: ol.control.defaults(),
            visible: true,
            logo: false
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the base map, but layer is not added on the basemap. Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: you have `CRS': 'EPSG:404000`, as your coordinate reference system , but that code actually means that GeoServer doesn't recognise the CRS (It's a GeoServer joke...) of your data, you'll need to first work out what the actual correct CRS  is.

Comment: Also BBOX, CRS, HEIGHT and WIDTH in your `params` and not needed as any values you supply will be overwritten with dynamically generated ones.  If the view projection is not supported by the WMS a projection which is supported must be specified as a `projection` option in `ol.source.TileWMS`  Projections other than EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 must have proj4 definitions registered.